# What oauthRedirectURL in openFB should look like, using a cordova app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, openfb

I came across this [openFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB/blob/master/index.html) plugin to make facebook requests without the sdk, that can be used in cordova,

I got it to log in the user in facebook, the thing is as oauthRedirectURL I end up in a white page, that says `Success` and I'm not sure how to get the user back to the app,

```
if (runningInCordova) {
oauthRedirectURL = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
}
```

Question is,

What url can i use to point my app ?

User ends up in this screen after the login

[image]

-edit-

I found solutions like `http://localhost.com/oauthcallback.html` but I don't have a apache2 in the cordova environament..

-2nd edit-

This is my current code,

```
openFB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy'});
openFB.login( function(response) {
     if(response.status === 'connected') {
         alert('Facebook login succeeded, got access token: ' + response.authResponse.token);
     } else {
         alert('Facebook login failed: ' + response.error);
     }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

This the line of the lib that fills this value

```
if (runningInCordova) {
    oauthRedirectURL = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used openFB before but I'm pretty sure it's based on the following docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3

If you go to the section "logging people in" you'll see the following message:

> redirect_uri. The URL that you want to redirect the person logging in
>   back to. This URL will capture the response from the Login Dialog. If
>   you are using this in a webview within a desktop app, this must be set
>   to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

When a FB user grants permissions to your App, it will be redirected to the url https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?access_token=new_token&...

What you have to do now is monitor this url and get the access token provided, which you should store with the fb user id in order to perform any API call.

Googling how to do this with openFB I found a thread at the openFB github repo that should help: https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB/issues/20#issuecomment-49249483 (is not totally related but it provides some code you can use)

This should be the code that will allow you to monitor the URL (extracted from the code provided on the thread):

```
if (runningInCordova) {
    loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
        var url = event.url;
        if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0) {
            // Get the token
        }
    });
}
```

Once you have obtained the access token and stored in your database, you should redirect to any other place of your App.

I hope it helps.

Javier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how the homepage url looks like? thanks again

Comment: What do you mean with "homepage url"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the document root of the app

Comment: Hi Toni, not sure I understand the question but if you are talking about what would be the homepage for your app, it should be your index.html in your www folder. If you want to know the path in the device, once you have installed the App, running window.location.href should return the path.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that produces an extra error.. is that it's not a http link (file:///android_asset/outhcallback.html) and facebook won't allowed as redirect_uri because its not "well formatted", any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, I wasn't including properly cordova.js.. that was the problem.. thanks anyways!